# Is it possible to have a segmentation fault from a reference?

Tags: c++

Suppose the following code:

```
Foo & foo = getFoo();
foo.attr; // 100% safe access?
```

If `foo` were a pointer, I would check if it is `NULL`, however because it is a reference, such checking is unecessary. What I want to know is if it is possible to mess up with an object's reference such that it would make accessing its attribute unsafe.

I tried some examples like trying to cast `NULL` to a `Foo` object, but I got compile errors. I just want to be sure that the above code is always safe, and that there is no possible inner `C++` black magic which I should be aware.

From Benjamin's answer, I could make an example code where I do get a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) from a reference, thus it answer my question. I'll paste my code just in case someone is interested in the future:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
    public:
    int x;
    B() {x = 5;}
};
class A
{
    public:
    void f()
    {
        b = *(B*)NULL;
    }
    B & getB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    B b;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.f();

    cout << a.getB().x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the `getFoo` function, to better answer your question.

Comment: In my real problem, `getFoo` has hundreds of lines of code, and the object that it returns may be modified by hundreds of threads... So no, it is not possible to make an example of `getFoo`.

Comment: @Kira: Note that your segfault is almost certainly from the statement `b = *(B*)NULL;` in the `f()` function. Not from `a.getB().x` in `main`.

Comment: It's possible for a reference to be invalid (as the answers below show) but **there is no way for you to check if it is invalid** so you should **not** waste time checking things like `if (&foo == NULL)` and trying to cope with it. If a function returns a reference then you assume it is a valid reference. If the function returns an invalid reference then that function is badly broken and you must fix the function, not try to make the callers cope with a function that has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Note that `Foo & foo = getFoo();` is dangerous if `getFoo()` does not actually return a reference but a value.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: If `getFoo()` does not return a reference then that code is ill-formed, because you can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary. Unless you are on MSVC, which allows it as an extension, in which case the reference extends the lifetime of the temporary, in the same way a const reference does in standard C++.

Comment: Correct - that's what I meant to say. A change to `getFoo()` to return a value instead of a reference may go unnoticed (at that point) on VS.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
Foo& Fr = *(Foo*)nullptr;
```

Technically, this is already undefined behavior for dereferencing that pointer. But it most likely won't result in any observable error. This probably will though:

```
Fr.attr = 10;
```

However, as Jonathan Wakely points out in the comments, there is no reason for you to check for a case like this. If a function returns an invalid reference, that function is broken, and needs to be fixed. Your usage code is not broken for assuming that the reference is valid. However, a valid reference can *become* invalid (though not null) in perfectly legitimate code, as mentioned in the answer by David Schwartz. But there is no way for you to check for this. You simply need to know in what cases it can happen, and then stop using the reference.

Comment: While this is true, this case can only occur in code that has a bug elsewhere. Surely cases where the access to the referenced object is the only bug are at least as important and at least deserve a mention.

Answer (score 26):

A reference must refer to a valid object when that reference is seated. This is a C++ standard requirement and any code that violates it is UB (undefined behavior) and could do literally anything.

However, it is perfectly legal to destroy the object a reference refers to after that reference is seated. At that point, accessing the reference is illegal. For example:

```
std::vector<int> j;
j.push_back(3);
int& k = j.front(); // legal, object exists now
j.clear();         // legal, object may be destroyed while reference exists
k++;              // illegal, destruction of object invalidates reference
```

This means a function that returns a reference must always return a reference that's valid when it's returned. This is why calling `front` on an empty vector is UB -- a reference must be valid when it's seated. However, there will often be conditions that can subsequently invalidate that reference, and you need to understand what those conditions are if you plan to try to stash the reference and access it later.

Generally, you should assume that it's unsafe to stash a returned reference and access it later unless you know that the reference will remain valid. For example, `std::vector` carefully explains under what conditions a reference into the container can be invalidated, and that includes a subsequent call to `push_back`. So this is broken:

```
std::vector<int> j;
j.push_back(3);
int &first = j.front();
j.push_back(4);
int &second = j.back();
if (first == second) // illegal, references into container are invalidated by push_back
```

But this is fine:

```
std::vector<int> j;
j.push_back(3);
j.push_back(4);
int &first = j.front();
int &second = j.back();
if (first == second) // legal, references into container stay valid
```

Comment: Note for OP, there is no way of detecting `k` is invalid before doing `k++` .  Validity of `k` is something you have to ensure through your program's logic in reaching that point.

Answer (score 17):

It is possible to have a reference to bad memory. And so the answer to `foo.attr; // 100% safe access?`, is no. Consider the following example:

```
int &something() {
    int i = 5, &j = i;
    return j; // Return reference to local variable. This is destroyed at end of scope. 
}

int main() {
    int &k = something(); // Equivalent to getFoo()
    std::cout << k << endl; // Using this reference is undefined behavior. 
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example.](http://ideone.com/YWTADt)

The reference k is not pointing to legitimate memory. But this will still compile. There is no case that this can happen however, where the programmer hasn't made a mistake. In this case, the function `something()` is written incorrectly and will need to be fixed. There is no way, or reason to check for this. If a function returns a bad reference then the only thing you can (and should) do is to fix the offending function.

Comment: I have the same objection to this answer as I do to Bejamin's. While true, this is the least important case to be aware of because it can only happen if there's a bug in code someplace else.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But i have mentioned this? I am not sure if it is clear, but in answer to this: `foo.attr; // 100% safe access?` I believe i have answered correctly. No ... if the programmer of `getFoo()` has made a mistake.

Comment: I have no issue with what you mentioned. My issue is with what you didn't mention -- that intervening code can make a valid reference no longer valid.