# C++ : Using an Enum type as a parameter

Tags: c++, enums

I defined my own Enum type as

```
enum Norm {norm1, norm2};
```

Now, in my `main()`, I am clustering an image using different type of norms.

The prototype of that being:

```
int extraction(char* cloudfile, float& maximumRadius, Norm norm);
```

And the part within `main()` where that function is called, being inside a `getops` switch, is:

```
extraction(argv[2], maximumRadius, norm2);
```

meaningful?

I tried to run several times, but gdb tells me there is a segmentation fault that I cannot find.

Hence my current question :

Can an Enum type be used as a parameter of a function? Or must I resort to predefined types?

Comment: why do you think the enum is the problem?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with an `enum` parameter. You can use strongly typed enums for more type safety. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581064/enum-vs-strongly-typed-enum

Comment: To paraphrase The Big Lebowski: *The Enum is not the issue.*

Comment: An enum is fine. You can even define what kind of fundamental type it is by using ":", e.g., "enum Norm : int {..., ...}". Your segfault is likely the argv[2] parameter, which is may be a null pointer. Use a debugger.

Comment: Is `argv[2]` valid? Did you run your program with at least two parameters? Did you check `argc` to verify it was at least 3? Does your code attempt to modify the string `cloudfile` points to?

Comment: To add a bit more context : I decided to tweak some of the functions. The only difference from the previous version is the addition of the Enum type. Hence my worries.

Comment: @Wyllich If the function exhibits undefined behavior - it may _seem_ to work correctly, throw segmentation fault, or do anything in-between, and beyond. The addition of another function argument, may have just changed what the function actually does, from such range of undefined possibilities. Without seeing the entire function - it's impossible, for us, to investigate whether it exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's absolutely possible to use an enum as function parameter. The segmentation fault came from another place.

Comment: Just to add an extra information to the question. 
Most of segmentation fault errors come from not proper C-pointer handle. 
It's also possible to get a segmentation from a reference (check this for a more in detail explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402055/is-it-possible-to-have-a-segmentation-fault-from-a-reference ).
The enum is not your problem here. If you are not forced to use C-pointers (e.g. legacy code, homework, etc), I would recommend you to check smart pointers: std::unique_ptr<> and std::shared_ptr<> .

Comment: The file exists, maximumRadius has been defined. This was the reasoning which led to my current question. But I'll keep investigating.

Comment: As an update, I found the error. You were correct is saying it was not in the Eum type. I was using std::vector::push_back() without std::vector::reserve() first.

Answer (score 0):

Enum types are just plain integers mapped to names. It is absolutely alright to use them as function parameters.

There is no possible way that this enum will cause the segmentation fault.
Segmentation fault is caused by trying to access memory that is not meant for your task. This is mostly caused by exceeding the allocated memory buffer or inappropriate pointer assignment.